# android changing background color too slow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-activityrecord

I want my program to have in every activity the same background color. So I put this line of code in every main layout of each layout.xml file.

```
android:background="@color/background"
```

So far so good, it works and looks nice. However, I recently started to notice when I call a new activity it first has a white background which changes immediately to the background color. But there is always this white color in my eyes for a very short time, which is really annoying.

Does anyone know how to avoid this problem? I want my activities to normally with their new background colors.

**Edit :**
Well every activity I use has the same background. That's how I start new activities :

```
startActivity( new Intent( getActivity(), ActivityAlbumContent.class ) );
```

So far I have only this one and the `MainActivity` but it's also on application start that the `MainActivity` has first a white background. I can now only assume that the Activities I will create later will have the same problem.

This is inside my styles.xml.

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
</style>
```

The windowBackground attribute does not exist somehow. I set this theme to my application in the manifest file but then it crashes.

```
06-30 20:43:49.048: E/AndroidRuntime(15411): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 20:43:49.048: E/AndroidRuntime(15411): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.davlog.mplayer/com.davlog.mplayer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-30 20:43:49.048: E/AndroidRuntime(15411):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
06-30 20:43:49.048: E/AndroidRuntime(15411):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
06-30 20:43:49.048: E/AndroidRuntime(15411):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:154)
06-30 20:43:49.048: E/AndroidRuntime(15411):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
06-30 20:43:49.048: E/AndroidRuntime(15411):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-30 20:43:49.048: E/AndroidRuntime(15411):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-30 20:43:49.048: E/AndroidRuntime(15411):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
06-30 20:43:49.048: E/AndroidRuntime(15411):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 20:43:49.048: E/AndroidRuntime(15411):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-30 20:43:49.048: E/AndroidRuntime(15411):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
06-30 20:43:49.048: E/AndroidRuntime(15411):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
06-30 20:43:49.048: E/AndroidRuntime(15411):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-30 20:43:49.048: E/AndroidRuntime(15411): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-30 20:43:49.048: E/AndroidRuntime(15411):    at com.davlog.mplayer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
06-30 20:43:49.048: E/AndroidRuntime(15411):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5255)
06-30 20:43:49.048: E/AndroidRuntime(15411):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
06-30 20:43:49.048: E/AndroidRuntime(15411):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2213)
06-30 20:43:49.048: E/AndroidRuntime(15411):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: How are you calling a new Activity? Please show some code.

Comment: @joao2fast4u I posted some edit. However, there is nothing special about calling my new activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`android:windowBackground`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowBackground) property in a custom theme to set the background color of an Activity, including when the Activity is loading.

For example, define this style:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/my_app_color</item>
</style>
```

Then in your manifest you select the theme like so:

```
<application
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp">

    <!- ... ->

</application>
```

This eliminates the need to set `android:background` for each of your layouts, and will display the appropriate color while Activities load.

Note that if you are supporting any devices above API 14, you probably want to have a `values-14/styles.xml` copy of this theme that inherits from a Holo theme. If you are only supporting devices above 14, then you only need one theme that inherits from a Holo theme.

Comment: eclipse doesn't show me the windowBackground attribute and when I set it, my app crashes with a nullpointerexception

Comment: Are you setting it in a theme, or trying to set it on a View in your layout's XML? The `NullPointerException` sounds completely unrelated, but your logcat should be able to provide more guidance as to where it is coming from.

Comment: If it is crashing with a `NullPointerException`, I can almost guarantee it is not caused by your style. The logcat message will tell you exactly which line of which class is causing the NPE- if it is one of your classes, find and fix that error. If it isn't one of your classes, post the complete log.

Comment: I posted the log, there are 11 missing but it won't show me.

Comment: I changed the parent to AppBaseTheme and now it seems to work. It does not crash and it shows me the correct background color. Thanks.